# how to store video in database using mysql?

Tags: mysql, video, store

I try to store a video file into database using MySQL, But i don't known how do store
video file into database. I try following query but it didn't work.

```
     CREATE TABLE GAME  (
               GAME_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
               GAME_NAME VARCHAR (20),
               VIDEO  LONGBLOB );


INSERT INTO GAME  VALUES(3, "Termonator2", 
LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos"));
```

Please give me any reference or hint.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the best practice is to store the video on the server itself, and then store the filename in the database.

Comment: _but it didn't work_ means what? What exactly happend? Error?

Comment: Use an RDBMS to store structured relational data. Don't use it to store files. That's what the filesystem is for.

Comment: you need to upload the video file on the server, and you'll save only the correct path to that file or the name with its extension

Comment: @OcasoProtal:no it doesn't show any error. i think it's query problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to add two slash in path.
Check following query.it's work with me.
use this

```
INSERT INTO GAME values (3, 'Termonator2',LOAD_FILE("C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos\\Sample Video\\test.mpg"));
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO GAME  VALUES(3, "Termonator2", 
LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos"));
```

enjoy.....

Comment: Yes, there are some special characters that they need to be escaped. Here the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html) with the list of "string literals".

Answer (score 19):

I would advise you to store the video file in a file directory, and only store the filename in your MySQL database.

This way, you can keep a light database.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I would suggest you to not store the video file in your database, this is a wrong approach.

Store only video file names and through which you can fetch video from a directory.

But your answer is:

```
INSERT INTO GAME values (3, 'Termonator2',LOAD_FILE("C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos\\Sample Video\\video.mp4"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos")` is a DIRECTORY. You forgot the video name and extension.

`Should be: LOAD_FILE("C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\videoname.avi")` for example.

But like everyone pointed out, this is a bad idea. Don't store videos in a database.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\filename.ending
```

instead of

```
C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your videos in the C: directory somewhere. The whole User/Videos thing seems to be hidden. I created a C:/videos directory and placed my videos in it!