# Adding different video's to products

Tags: html, sql, database

For school i have to make a webshop. We got a database with products and its details in it where we work with. Most of it is done in html. To the site i want to add a video for the product. I only got this bit from some google searches:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Now the problem with this is that it is for one specific video. Since the products are taken out of a database there are no specific lines of code for each product. So how do i bind a different video for each of the products in the database?

Here is how the site looks now, the red bit indiciates where i want the video to be.
[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: this will help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383886/how-to-store-video-in-database-using-mysql

Comment: as far as i understand from your question you want to bind a video url for each product is that right?

Comment: @MohammadAlBaghdadi kind of, yea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using MySQL.

Let's say you have a table called 'product', which stores the information about your products.

1) If you need a single video for a single product (that's called a one-to-one relationship), then there should be a column that stores the path to the video, either from the internet, or on your machine.
The MySQL statement looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `webshop`.`product` (
`product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`video_path` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`));
```

And in order to get the products use:

```
SELECT * FROM product;
```

2) If your product may have multiple videos attached (many-to-one relationship), 
you will need 3 tables: one for products:

```
CREATE TABLE `webshop`.`product` (
`product_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`));
```

one for path :

```
CREATE TABLE `path` (
`path_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`video_path` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`path_id`));
```

then create another database, that will contain a products's id and a path's id. The create table statement should look something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `product_path` (
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `path_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`path_id`),
 KEY `fk_path_id_idx` (`path_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_path_id` FOREIGN KEY (`path_id`) REFERENCES `path` 
 (`path_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` 
 (`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

In order to get all products:

```
SELECT * FROM product 
INNER JOIN product_path ON product.product_id = product_path.product_id 
INNER JOIN path ON product_path.path_id = path.path_id;
```