# expo-av recorded file location

Tags: react-native, expo

When I record it generates a file, but I can't figure out where this file is?

This is what the output of the app:
`Recording stoped and stored at file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Faudio-99dec697-bfba-4734-9439-edd02e8d4dc4/Audio/recording-656419bd-781b-4162-b111-36d11e7e3e15.m4a`

Comment: I have understood that expo save the media in the caché and not in the local storage. What you want to do with the file?

Comment: I'm working on a school project which requires me to record audio process it and store it in a db.

Comment: This could help you, just use the uri that expo provides you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383886/how-to-store-video-in-database-using-mysql

Comment: the link you shared is about storing in a database. I'm currently just looking for the location or a way to access the file.