# Where does expo-av recorded file store in mobile phones?

Tags: react-native, voice-recording, expo-av

I am trying to have access to the actual file that the expo-av creates after every recording but I can not access it from any file explorer app and my goal is to upload it on a server and in a db. This question is related to this question too but still there is no answer. ([expo-av recorded file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052845/expo-av-recorded-file-location/75367213?noredirect=1#comment132986805_75367213))

Comment: Have you tried the `getURI()` method? According to the [doc](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#geturi), this method seems to reveal the location of the recording. Also check out the [example](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#recording-sounds) for usage of `getURI()`.

Comment: @FanchenBao yes I check the method and I have this result "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fmy-app-43e94360-5934-4fd1-95cc-a6eb18200013/Audio/recording-93303d" but when I am trying to follow the location there is not such a file

Comment: Try [this](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemuploadasyncurl-fileuri-options) method. The `url` should be an API endpoint. I suppose you will have to create this API. In the API, you can accept the uploaded recording, convert it to any format you want, and save it in your DB.